# how to save the outputs of a code in CSV files in julia

Tags: csv, julia

I know this is a beginnerquestion but i'm having problems in saving my data into a CSV file for example like in this code:

```
function mar(x,y)
for i in 1:10
s=x*i+y
end
end
```

how to save `s`and `x`and `y` i just would like to know the procedure that's all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`CSV.jl`](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/) library, which includes the [`CSV.write`](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/#CSV.write) function. Example:

```
julia> using CSV                                       

julia> x = rand(10); y = rand(10); s = (1:10).*x .+ y;

julia> CSV.write("out.csv", (s = s, x = x, y = y))
```

Here I'm constructing a `NamedTuple` from `s`, `x`, and `y`, which satisfies the `Tables.jl` interface and therefore can be written out to file by `CSV.jl` like any other table.

Comment: what if i want to do it inside a function in a more simple way

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You can of course call `CSV.write` in a function in the same way? CSV is a tabular data format, so two things you likely won't get around are (1) creating some 2-dimensional structure to hold the data you want to write and (2) actually calling some sort of `write` function. That's all that's happening in my example above, so not sure how to make it "more simple"?

Comment: i mean whithout changing the example of the code that i put in the question because actually the real code is quite big and i can't change its shape

Comment: I constructed `s`, `x` and `y` slightly differently from your code to make it a working example, but you can just stick `CSV.write("out.csv", (s = s, x = x, y = y))` after your `for` loop and it should work, no?